# OpenCV's Mat.put() is not working / not updating matrix

Tags: java, opencv

OpenCV's Mat.put() method is not working for me. It doesn't update anything on the given matrix.

```
    Mat myMat = new Mat();
    myMat.put(0, 0, 1);
    System.out.println(myMat.dump()); // Prints "[]" instead of a not empty matrix
```

My system: OpenCV 3.1, Java, Mac OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I'm not using the empty constructor for the Mat object. For example:
 `new Mat(1,1, CvType.CV_32FC1);`